# Raster reprojection with GDAL in C++

Tags: raster, gdal, gdalwarp, c++

I'm working in a GIS program with C++ and in this moment, i'm working in my raster visor.

I need reproject my Raster in ejecution time, but i dont want create a output file with this reprojected Raster. For this reason i can't use GDALWarp.

Does anyone have any idea how to reproject the raster without creating a new output file?

I think if I got the GeoTransform information from the reprojected Raster it would be enough

Comment: You can use GDALWarp. Suggest you investigate outputting to MEM format, or use the /vsimem virtual filesystem to output an in-memory geotiff/VRT/other preferred raster format (i.e. write to /vsimem/somerandomfilename.tif). Assuming you are using the `GDALWarpOperation` method, not the `gdalwarp` command line tool. See http://www.gdal.org/warptut.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an in-memory raster dataset with the [`MEM` driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mem.html). This will create a raster in the RAM and not require a file on the filesystem. Once the in-memory raster is created you can utilize it just like any other `GDALDataset`.